# Relative flatness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Can someone me say if this (perhaps obvious!) claim  is true:

let $f:X\rightarrow S$ be an open, surjective morphism of complex spaces reduced or without embedded components and with $n$-pure dimensional fibers. Let $F$, $G$ be a coherent sheaves with $S$-depth bigger than $2$ and  s.t:

1) $G$ is $S$-flat

2) there is a canonical injective morphism $F\rightarrow G$

3)  $F$ and $G$ are locally isomorphics.

Question: Is $F$ $S$-flat too?

Rk: Of course, the answer is yes if the Coker of 2) is $S$-flat.

Thanks.

Comment: $S$-flatness is a local property, so 1) and 3) imply that $F$ is $S$-flat, without any further assumptions. Or am I missing something? 

Comment: What do you mean that F and G are locally isomorphic, by the way?  If F and G are sheaves, and $F\to G$ is a local isomorphism, doesn't that imply that they are honestly isomorphic (since sheafification _is_ localization at local isomorphisms of presheaves)?

Comment: @Harry: Locally isomorphic does not mean that there is a global morphism that gives the local isomorphism. For instance, any two line bundles are locally isomorphic, but there may not be a morphism between them. Or there may be one, say one could be a subsheaf of the other, but the local isomorphism is not given by the global morphism.


Comment: At the same time, I don't know what could a "canonical injective morphism" mean between two concrete sheaves without any functors producing them.

Comment: @Sándor: What use would we have for "locally isomorphic" sheaves in that sense? Isn't it generally considered good practice for locally isomorphic objects to at least be _morphic_?

Comment: Usually not: for instance local coefficient systems are sheaves which are locally isomorphic to locally constant sheaves, but they are not themselves locally constant.

Comment: Actually I cannot think any example where one requires locally isomorphic objects to have a global morphism. For instance, differentiable manifolds are locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, regardless of their global morphisms to or from $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Andrea: I think there's a difference between saying that two objects are locally isomorphic and saying that an object is locally isomorphic to some class of objects or locally has a property (i.e. that it admits some notion of an open cover by such objects).  That is, "locally euclidean" and "locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbf R^n$" mean something very different).  In your sheaf example, as far as I can find in a cursory look around the internet, these guys are "locally constant sheaves".

Comment: 

Be careful, Laurent, the local isomorphism is on ${\cal O}_{X}$, flatness is local on $X$; so it is no so obvious to pass from ${\cal O}_{X,x}$ to ${\cal O}_{S,f(x)}$.

It is no hard to see that for $f$ flat,  1) and 3) imply the $S$-flatness of $F$ (and then 2) can be ommitted...). 

But, in general, without flatness assumptions on $f$,  i think that 2) must be essential...


Rk: see for instance [EGA4], prop (11.3.7),p.135 or the similar results in analytic geometry [Banica-Stanasila], 1.5,p.194, 4.6,p.225.




Comment: Kaddar, could you explain what you mean by "locally isomorphic"?

Comment: Locally isomorphic means that for every $x\in X$ there is a suff. small  open neighbourhood on which we have an  isomorphism between this sheaves (you can think this as a "germe" ).

Comment: Then as you said, flatness is local on $X$ and so is $S$-flatness. I still don't see the problem.

Comment: @Shawn: But this other notion of "locally isomorphic" is useless as well.  The main point is that there is an open cover such that $S|_{U_i}$ is isomorphic to a flat sheaf on an open cover $U_i$.  This basically has no bearing at all on whether or not we can assemble everything into a sheaf at all.  The notion of local isomorphism I mentioned means "isomorphic in the localization", implying that there is at least a zigzag of local isomorphisms.  This is a standard definition.  

Comment: The problem for me is that an $O_{X,x}$-isomorphism is not necessarily an $O_{S,f(x)}$-isomorphism...

Comment: @Harry: I don't know where this is a "standard" definition. How about *locally free*? Do you need a morphism to or from a free sheaf for that?

Comment: @kaddar: What do you mean by "...an $O_{X,x}$-isomorphism is not necessarily an $O_{S,f(x)}$-isomorphism..."? why not? Isn't $f$ a morphism?

Comment: In my mind,  an  $O_{X}$-local isomorphism $u:F\rightarrow G$ is not necessarily an $O_{S}$-isomorphism...

As we can see, the flatness of $f$ seems to be a necessary condition.

Comment: @Sandor: That's true, but that's also not what I said. Nobody would say that a locally free sheaf is "locally isomorphic to a free sheaf". That's meaningless.  Locally isomorphic has a precise meaning in the sense that two presheaves are $\tau$-locally isomorphic if there exists a $\tau$-local isomorphism between them (that is, their sheafifications are isomorphic) where $\tau$ is any system of data determining a Grothendieck topology (specifying local isomorphisms, local epimorphisms, sieves, or covers satisfying their respective axioms all determine such a grothendieck topology).  

Comment: Here's a link:http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/local+isomorphism .  It has references as well.  

Answer (score 0):

For a flat map $f$, we can see the $S$-flatness of $F$ as follow:

Let $x\in X$ and denote by: $A:=O_{S,f(x)}$, $B:=O_{X,x}$, ${\rm F}:=F_{x}$ and ${\rm G}:=G_{x}$. The $S$-flatness of the coherent sheaf $F$ in $x$ is, by definition, the $A$-flatness of the module (of finite type) ${\rm F}$ or, equivalently, the left exactness of the functor $K\rightarrow {\rm F}\otimes_{A} K$ where $K$  is $A$-module of finite type. Take a left exact sequenz of $A$-modules
$$0\rightarrow K\rightarrow L$$
which give us a  morphism ${\rm F}\otimes_{A}K\rightarrow {\rm F}\otimes _{A} L$ or equivalently  a morphism

$${\rm F}{\otimes_{B}}(B\otimes_{A} K)\rightarrow {\rm F}\otimes_{B}(B\otimes_{A} L)$$

We can replace ${\rm F}$ by ${\rm G}$ at this moment and see that the injectivity of the desired map is obtained if we assume $B$ is $A$-flat module because  $B\otimes_{A} K\rightarrow B\otimes_{A} L$ is injective and ${\rm G}$ is $A$-flat.